# H2 in Memory trims trailing blanks

Tags: java, jdbc, h2

I'm utilizing an in-memory H2 Database for automated tests of a legacy system.

`jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=Oracle`

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (MYCOLUMN CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES(' ');
SELECT '*' || MYCOLUMN || '*' FROM MYTABLE;
```

This statement returns `* *` on the Oracle db, but returns `**` on the H2 db.

This leads to errors when testing.

How can I disable the trimming of char columns?

I cannot change the legacy code.
I cannot change the legacy statements.
I cannot change the legacy column types.

The tables for testing are created automatically; I could change behavior on that side.

Comment: That you cannot change anything about the legacy code (Java, DDL, or DML) makes testing it on a different database highly questionable.  Different DBs exhibit behavioral differences.  There are ways to try to abstract those away, but you're constrained not to use them.

Comment: Or from the other direction, testing against a different DB version than you use in production is a poor idea.  Even if your tests pass against H2, you can't be confident about what that means for the same code running against Oracle.

Comment: Heck, I've once or twice run into issues just with a difference between two versions of Oracle tripping me up.

Comment: At the moment there are practically no tests regarding the db and queries, it can just get better

Comment: It can get better in the sense that there are more tests, yes, but that's a dubious benefit when you have to be concerned that those tests are wrong.  It's very difficult to validate them when they run against a different version of the DBMS.  Indeed, that's exactly what this question is about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using an entirely outdated version of H2, all modern versions don't trim trailing spaces from `CHARACTER` (`CHAR`) values. You need to upgrade your version of H2 to 2.*.*.

Comment: I just checked, I was using a the managed version of the maven project, it was 1.4.184, now going to 2.2.224

Comment: The newest version behaves like you said

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change the char to varchar(1) like below

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (MYCOLUMN VARCHAR(1));
```

because the char type will pad the spaces and trimmed while retrieving.